# What is the effect on measured values of potential differences if we assume that potential difference of earth is +100V instead of zero?

Tags: electromagnetism

What is the effect on measured value of potential differences of earth is +100V instead of zero?

Comment: Hi Vîrsã. Can you clarify what you are asking? Potential has a gauge symmetry and we can add a constant to the potential without affecting anything. Only **potential differences** can be measured. However the potential of the Earth is normally defined with respect to a vacuum at infinity, and if you're talking about charging the earth to +100V relative to the vacuum by adding or removing charges then that's a different situation.